# Next.js 13: Module not found when referencing package with CSS @ font paths

Tags: css, next.js

I'm using Next.js 13.4.2 and I've added an npm package that contains some CSS and fonts. I'm trying to use one of the CSS files in my app and running into an issue. In `layout.tsx` I 've imported the CSS file:

```
import '@leap/core-thin/core.classic-dark.css';
```

When I run the project I get the following error:

```
../../node_modules/@leap/core-thin/core.classic-dark.css:4:0
Module not found: Can't resolve './@leap/core-thin/fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2'
```

The CSS that causes the issue:

```css
@font-face {
  src: url("@leap/core-thin/fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2") format("woff2"), url("@leap/core-thin/fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

If I modify the paths in the css file to use a relative path it seems to work, but I don't own the package so is there some other way of configuring my project so that it can translate the paths correctly?

Comment: I cannot find this package. What did you install?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use fonts that are downloaded and imported, you have to use localFont from next and make the changes in the `app.js` file.

```
import localFont from 'next/font/local';

const BeVietnamFont = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: '../../public/fonts/BeVietnam-Light.ttf',
      weight: '300',
      style: 'normal',
    },
    {
      path: '../../public/fonts/BeVietnam-Regular.ttf',
      weight: '400',
      style: 'normal',
    },
    {
      path: '../../public/fonts/BeVietnam-Bold.ttf',
      weight: '700',
      style: 'normal',
    },
  ],
  display: 'swap',
});
```

[Nextjs Local Font](https://import%20localFont%20from%20%27next/font/local%27;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const withCSS = require("@leap/core-thin/"); // your package path
module.exports = withCSS({
  cssModules: true
});
```

OR

In the next.config.js file, import the necessary webpack modules by including the following code:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
```

Next, define your custom webpack configuration by adding the following code:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
     config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve("./node_modules"));
    }
    return config;
  },
};
```

In this configuration, we use the resolve.modules property to add the node_modules directory as a location to look for imported modules.

Save the next.config.js file and restart your Next.js development server. Now, you can import CSS styles directly from the node_modules folder in your Next.js components using the regular import syntax.